Azure Pipeline Docker build fails to use cache while building
I'm encountering an error in my Azure Pipeline when trying to build a Docker image using cache from a previous build. Here's the relevant part of my pipeline YAML:
yaml
- task: Docker@2
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    Dockerfile: '**/Dockerfile'
    arguments: '--cache-from=$(imageName):latest'

When this runs, I get the following error:
#6 ERROR: failed to configure registry cache importer: pull access denied, repository does not exist or may require authorization: server message: insufficient_scope: authorization failed

I'm not using Azure Container Registry to store my images. The pipeline is working and building the docker container, but it's not using the cache from the previous build.
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Did you use Cache@2 task to cache the image? or pushed the image at the pipeline end to reuse in next run?


#6 ERROR: failed to configure registry cache importer: pull access denied, repository does not exist or may require authorization: server message: insufficient_scope: authorization failed

It typically occurs when Docker is unable to access the specified image in the registry due to authentication issues or because the image does not exist.
You can try to run docker pull $(imageName):latest to check if you are able to pull. Make sure the imagename, tag is correct as you pushed in previous run.
If not, consider to add the service connection in your Docker task for authentication. Here’s an example:
- task: Docker@2
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    Dockerfile: '**/Dockerfile'
    arguments: '--cache-from=$(imageName):latest'
    containerRegistry: 'your-service-connection-name'

